# C# WPF Grid Columns misinterpreted

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've started developing a new application in WPF C#. The problem I'm having is regarding grid column definitions.

I have divided my Window into separate sections, using Grids' row and col definitions (see code below).

I have two rows. First is currently empty, second one contains a new grid, that is further divided into columns.
All grids are inside a border.

The weird behavior I'm getting, is this section of the code:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#ffcd22"  Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid>

                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#ffcd22"  Grid.Column="2">
                <Grid>

                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#ffcd22"  Grid.Column="3">
                <Grid>

                </Grid>
            </Border>
```

> The problem is, that the first "subgrid" actually corresponds to the
>   second column, The second and third both refer to the third column.
>   In other words, whenever I put any kind of control in the second subgrid (the one which has Grid.Column="2"), the control will appear in the third column for some reason.

I've been fiddling around with it, and can't seem to understand the behavior I'm getting.

Another example: I've put a control in the second column as following:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#ffcd22"  Grid.Column="2">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox Width="100" Height="50"></TextBox>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
```

The image below represents what I got: 
[image]

**Whole XAML code:**

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#ffcd22" Margin="10,10,10,10">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#ffcd22" Margin="-1,-1,-1,-1" Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#ffcd22"  Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid>

                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#ffcd22"  Grid.Column="2">
                    <Grid>

                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#ffcd22"  Grid.Column="3">
                    <Grid>

                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: 3 ColumnDefinitions have indices 0,1,2, not 1,2,3 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the column numeration starts from 0. You should change your code like this:

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#ffcd22"  Grid.Column="0">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Border>
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#ffcd22"  Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Border>
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#ffcd22"  Grid.Column="2">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: Whoah. I was so deep into the problem that I had overlooked such an obvious thing. Thanks heaps!